# CircleCI Console Unlock Password?

Tags: mongodb, circleci

We unfortunately had a developer leave without sharing our CircleCI unlock password, so I am in the process of trying to pull it out of our VM. I am wondering where the `Unlock the console` password is stored in CircleCI, if it is plain text or maybe if its hiding in MongoDB or some other mechanism. Thanks for the help.

Picture attached for clarity

**UPDATE** We are using Enterprise and I was able to [surface this out of the docs](http://circleci.com/docs/enterprise/config/)

```
curl https://s3.amazonaws.com/circleci-enterprise/init-builder-0.2.sh | \
  SERVICES_PRIVATE_IP=<private ip address of services box> \
  CIRCLE_SECRET_PASSPHRASE=<passphrase entered on system console (services box port 8800) settings> \
  CIRCLE_CONFIG_OPTION_1=<value> \
  CIRCLE_CONFIG_OPTION_2=<value> \
  bash
```

```

After looking at the bash script though it doesn't look like its actually DOING anything with the var? Weirdness....

[image: Circle CI Rescue]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Can you please try the following?

SSH into the services box and run `sudo replicated auth reset`. Then, visit `https://<YOUR_CCIE_HOSTNAME>:8800/create-password` to create a new console password. Replace `<YOUR_CCIE_HOSTNAME>` with the hostname CircleCI Enterprise is running on. Please let us know if it works/doesn't work.

-Ricardo
Developer Evangelist, CircleCI